# Spring @RequestBody Bad Request

Tags: java, json, spring

I am using POSTMAN to send request's.

Configured all right there:

- Content-Type application/json
- Request Type POST
  and in Body I have the following:

```
{
    "token":"EAACEdEose0cBAFLc4blCYmmetEMBEZCiQQZAuvz6DlxFt0yPZCksZBWv09B71aZCeDH9zOPyzM44GRl8WA56uFZBmOiUMmSlk3USfOwRdwmXDnhlPArttzjjLzUXaTReHzHZC7ZCcFzZADwGBLRUHvTb17nagRDLpZBysdxZBxuJuojlgZDZD"
}
```

I POST this to a controller and get a 400 BAD Request Error:

```
{
"timestamp": 1475061564742,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "Could not read document: Can not construct instance of at.wastun.controller.WTUserController$RegisterBody: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@a646ac6; line: 2, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of at.wastun.controller.WTUserController$RegisterBody: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@a646ac6; line: 2, column: 2]",
"path": "/users/register"
}
```

The class and the Controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
@ResponseBody
public class WTUserController {

    private class RegisterBody{
        private String token;

        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }

        public RegisterBody(String fbToken){
            this.token = fbToken;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String method0(@RequestBody RegisterBody body){
        return body.getToken();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of both answers @Andremoniy and @Mr Spoon

Worked after I made the class

```
public static class RegisterBody {
```

and removed the constructor and made it to an default constructor.

```
public static class RegisterBody{
        private String token;

        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }
    }
```

Works now thanks

Comment: That's cool, but I'm sure that my suggestion about making class non-private and adding default constructor would solve your problem also.

Answer (score 1):

Your RegisterBody class is private.  So nothing outside of the code in your class can create new instances of it.  Try:

```
public static class RegisterBody {
```

Or, better still, move RegisterBody into its own java file.

Comment: Also won't work, got this error in the Java Console (edited above)

Answer (score 1):

The error itself tells you about origin of the problem: `no suitable constructor found`. So you need to add *default* constructor into `RegisterBody` class. Also I'm not sure that making this class `private` good idea.

Answer (score 0):

When Spring tries to resolve `Body` it creates the object with a default constructor `ClassName()` and then tries to fill the fields with setters. So if you want to resolve `RequestBody` into `RegisterBody` it should look like below:

```
private class RegisterBody{
    private String token;

    public RegisterBody() {};

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public RegisterBody(String fbToken){
        this.token = fbToken;
    }
}
```

Apart from that remember, that Spring implements MVC for some reason. Put the classes to `Utils` or `Misc` `package` if you can't classify it better but DON'T declare classes in `Controller`s!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an empty constructor for the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Lombok you can use the following annotations:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
// Must include this annotation since Spring instantiates the @ResponseBody type with no args.
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomRequestBody {
    private String message;
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class ReactiveRestController {

    @PostMapping("/api/test")
    public Mono<CustomResponse> post(@RequestBody CustomRequestBody requestBody) {
        log.info(requestBody.getMessage());
        return Mono.just(new CustomResponse(200, "success"));
    }
}
```